# где взять все данные значки с плеера

Tags: html, css

здраствуйте, верстаю первый пет - проект, да и вообще впервые что-то верстаю настолько "глобальное", хочу сделать функциональным данным скрин, для этого решил полностью сверстать весь плеер, но не могу найти данные значки(которые обвел красным), подскажите, где найти эти значки? и подскажите пожалуйста, какой шрифт используется для название треков. заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: За иконками https://icons8.ru/icons/ios в помощь. Фонт думаю San Francisco Pro. В Google Fonts его нету, но есть аналоги

Answer (score 0):

Если нужны готовые паки иконок, то для таких вещей есть библиотеки:

- [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/v6/search)
- [Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)
- [Material Icons](https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html#design-principles)

И много еще других на просторах интернета. Не ленитесь и ищите сами.

В вашем случае даже [символы Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_control_symbols) можно применить.

Comment: спасибо, воспользуюсь, я искал, нашел даже пак значков от apple, но к сожалению они для mac, а не для мобильной версии